# opencv identifiers like 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT' and 'CV_BGR2GRAY' are undefined in vs

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a bunch of these undefined identifiers like 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT' and 'CV_BGR2GRAY' but my headers don't have any errors and seem to be linked properly:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

I have used libraries with c++ before but I am still new so I do not know what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's the old C API, which has been unsupported for a very long time, deprecated in 3.0 , and removed in 4.0 (~end of 2018). Use the C++ API.

Comment: i.e. write `cv::CAP_PROP_...` instead. use the docs: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939

Comment: @DanMašek I see, thank you