# How to Add Library to Visual Studio - OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Im trying to add OpenCV to Visual Studio, and afer following the instructions from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unSce_GPwto&ab_channel=BoostMyTool , it returned that it was not built succesfuly.

To start off, what i have already done:

- I added Path to Enviroment Variables
- added the path "C:\Users\Uporabnik\Documents\Library\opencv\build\ **include**" to
  project/properties/c#c++/general/**addittional include directories**
- added the path "C:\Users\Uporabnik\Documents\Library\opencv\build\x64\vc15\ **lib**" to project/properties/linker/general/**addittional library directories**
- added "**opencv_world460.lib**" to project/properties/linker/input/**addittional dependencies**

when all was done, i ran the build solution and it returnes not succesfull.
im used to python on PyCharm, where adding libraries is as easy ass pressing add library, so this has been an annoying experiance so far

the error message after "build/build solution":

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: hhh, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>hhh.cpp
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(11,39): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(12,45): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(20,40): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(20,79): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(21,46): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(21,88): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(23,62): error C3861: 'CV_FOURCC': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(53,1): error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\hhh.cpp(53,2): error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(11,39): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(12,45): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(20,40): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(20,79): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(21,46): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(21,88): error C2065: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(23,62): error C3861: 'CV_FOURCC': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(53,1): error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
1>C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh\main.cpp(53,2): error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
1>Done building project "hhh.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:04,338 ==========
```

Comment: please bare with me, im new to programing in general, and even more new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you have an #include for opencv stuff in your files hhh.cpp and main.cpp (or in a common h file included by both) ?

Comment: No i do not have the include folder in C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\C#\hhh\hhh where hhh.cpp and main.cpp are located

Comment: Your steps seem reasonable. The last step could get you into trouble:  ***added "opencv_world460.lib" to project/properties/linker/input/addittional dependencies***  Remember this is the Release library. It will be incompatible with the debug configuration so you can't use that library if you need to use debug mode.

Comment: @wohlstad if i may ask, im very curious to know, how come you answer on stackoverflow so much, in other words you are top 0.16% this month, and im wondering is there any added benefit beside having helped a lot of people on this website. What is the motive?

Comment: You can consider it a hobby of mine :-)

Comment: Maybe you have a bug in your code and this question is a duplicate of this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679460/opencv-identifiers-like-cv-cap-prop-frame-count-and-cv-bgr2gray-are-undefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679460/opencv-identifiers-like-cv-cap-prop-frame-count-and-cv-bgr2gray-are-undefine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's an error compiling, not a linker error, so it can be relatively few things.

1. Verify that `hhh.cpp` and `main.cpp` include the correct OpenCV header(s).
2. Verify those headers are actually in `C:\Users\Uporabnik\Documents\Library\opencv\build\include`or are in folders accessible by relative paths rooted there that correspond to the relative paths in your include directives.
3. Verify you have added that path to "Additional Include Directories" in the properties *of the configuration you are trying to build*.

Without additional information my guess would be your problem is 3. The "configuration" in Visual Studio is typically a pair of parameters, either Debug or Release along with the architecture, x86 (often displayed as "Win32" in VS) or x64. I can see from the error messages you are trying to build "Release x64".

Go into properties and make sure you have made the addition to "Additional Include Directories" in the configuration "Release x64". It is an easy mistake to make to accidently set properties only for Debug or only for x86, etc.